# Passing CallbackFunction as Parameter for Ajax-Request

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I want to get content for my website asynchronously. Now that I have more than one requests for my server I thought it would be great to seperate the "conntection Stuff" into another function:

```
function conToServerAsync( url, postParams, func )
{
   var xmlHttp;
   if( window.XMLHttpRequest )
   {
      xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
   else
   {
      xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
   xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = func;
   xmlHttp.open("POST", url, true);
   xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
   xmlHttp.send(postParams);
}
```

Now I have this other function which is executing the "conToServerAsync" function like this:

```
function findSearchResult(value)
{
  conToServerAsync( "Classes/Async/liveSearch.php", "sVal="+value, function()
  {
    if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
    {
    document.getElementById("searchResult").innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
    document.getElementById("searchResult").style.border="1px solid #A5ACB2";
    }
  });
}
```

Now whats actually interesting about my case is that I've checked everything and every parameter that is passed in is valid. Then I tried to allocate the function that is given in the last parameter "conToServerAsync( "Classes...", "sVal..", function(){...}" directly to the onreadystatechange:

```
...
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
            {
            document.getElementById("searchResult").innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
            document.getElementById("searchResult").style.border="1px solid #A5ACB2";
            }
      }
```

... and it works perfectly :S So definitly the error is about passing the function on a wrong way and I have no idea. Cos my case is that specific I made a own question about it.

Thank you for answering :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to use `xmlHttp` from the callback, but it's out of scope. I suggest the following approach:

```
function conToServerAsync( url, postParams, func )
{
   var xmlHttp;
   if( window.XMLHttpRequest )
   {
      xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
   else
   {
      xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
   xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
         func.call(xmlHttp, xmlHttp);
      }
   }
   xmlHttp.open("POST", url, true);
   xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
   xmlHttp.send(postParams);
}

function findSearchResult(value)
{
  conToServerAsync( "Classes/Async/liveSearch.php", "sVal="+value, function(xhr)
  {
    document.getElementById("searchResult").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
    document.getElementById("searchResult").style.border="1px solid #A5ACB2";
  });
}
```

Comment: @Musa Nice, changed the code to allow both styles (admittedly not using `this` in places that I could use it).

Comment: @bfavaretto that's not really what I meant, I posted an answer of what I meant.

Comment: @Musa Oh I see. That would work too, of course, but I prefer my solution or Vitim.us', as they only invoke the callback when the response is ready, so you don't have to check for readyState and status on every ajax callback.

Answer (score 1):

On my implementation of the XMLHttp wrapper I use the [Function.prototype.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to call the callback function from the XMLHttp Object scope, So you can use the keyword `this` to access properties and I also pass the responseText as a parameter for convenience.

```
if(typeof func=="function")
    func.call(xmlHttp, xmlHttp.responseText);
```

You can easily print the response on the callback

```
function callback(response){
    alert(response);
}
```

But you can still have access to all properties of the XMLHttp Object

```
function callback(response){
    alert(this.status); //200
    alert(response);
}
```

Full code:

```
function conToServerAsync( url, postParams, func ){

   var xmlHttp;
   if( window.XMLHttpRequest ){
      xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
   else{
      xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
   xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if(xmlHttp.readyState==4 && xmlHttp.status==200){
        if(typeof func=="function")
            func.call(xmlHttp, xmlHttp.responseText);
      }
   }
   xmlHttp.open("POST", url, true);
   xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
   xmlHttp.send(postParams);
}

function findSearchResult(value){

  conToServerAsync( "Classes/Async/liveSearch.php", "sVal="+value, function(response){
    document.getElementById("searchResult").innerHTML = response;
    document.getElementById("searchResult").style.border="1px solid #A5ACB2";
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the function you passed to `xmlHttp.onreadystatechange` is called with `xmlHttp` as the context you can use `this` to refer to that object.

```
function findSearchResult(value)
{
  conToServerAsync( "Classes/Async/liveSearch.php", "sVal="+value, function()
  {
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
    {
    document.getElementById("searchResult").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    document.getElementById("searchResult").style.border="1px solid #A5ACB2";
    }
  });
}
```